# Scrolling through ListView of ProgressBars

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-progressbar

I'm working on an Android app that utilizes a ListView, in which each row is comprised of a text view and a progress bar. Things work smoothly unless the user has to scroll through a long list.

ProgressBars start taking on the progress of other ProgressBars not currently visible on the screen.

I understand that this is a common issue that stems from the implementation of GetView, but I'm wondering what the best course of action is to take with ProgressBars.

GetView:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        View row = convertView;
        ViewWrapper wrapper;
        ProgressBar myProgressBar;
        int initProgress = myData.get(position).getProgress();

        if (row == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null); 

            wrapper = new ViewWrapper(row);
            row.setTag(wrapper);    
        }

        else{
            wrapper = (ViewWrapper)row.getTag();

        }

        RowModel model = getModel(position);        
        wrapper.getPid().setText(model.toString());
        myProgressBar = wrapper.getProgressBar();
        myProgressBar.setProgress(initProgress);
        myProgressBar.setMax(100);

        myProgressBar.setTag(new Integer(position));

        return row;
    }
```

ViewWrapper:

```
public class ViewWrapper {
    View base;
    TextView pid = null;
    ProgressBar pb= null;

    ViewWrapper(View base){
        this.base = base;
    }

    TextView getPid(){
        if(pid == null){
            pid = (TextView)base.findViewById(R.id.pid);
        }

        return(pid);
    }

    ProgressBar getProgressBar(){
        if(pb== null){
            pb= (ProgressBar)base.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        }

        return(pb);
    }
}
```

It seems that the issue is related to:

```
myProgressBar = wrapper.getProgressBar();
```

because that ProgressBar starts getting the behavior of a recycled ProgressBar. However, I want it to have its own behavior.

What's the best way to alleviate this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to inflate the layout each time and not re-use the convertView that's passed in.   This shouldn't be a problem unless  you have A LOT of rows.

Answer (score 0):

I had to implement a similar feature , here is what I did . I implemented the following outside `getview`

- OnTouchListener - to listen to seekbar touch events
- OnKeyListener - to listen to dpad and trakball event for the seekbar

I set these listeners for the seekbars from `getView`

Whenever the listeners were called , I would find the seekbars parent , then do the `findviewbyid` from the parent to the textview.

So now I have the textview which I have to update, and the seekbar.  All I need to do was set the text from the array.

here is some code to help you.

private OnTouchListener touchListener = new OnTouchListener() {

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            View parent = (View) v.getParent();
            TextView textView = (TextView) parent
                    .findViewById(R.id.id_grade_tooltip);
            if (textView == null) {
            } else {
                SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) v;
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(seekBar.getProgress())
                        + "%");
            }
            return false;
    }
};
```